# Removing padding from a Bootstrap image in a fluid container?

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, containers, padding

I'm trying to get an image to run edge to edge (full width) within the viewport under Bootstrap 4. I had thought that the `container-fluid` element would allow this, by housing a `row` which could then contain the `img` element, as opposed to the `container` element which would constrain the width.

Nothing i do seems capable of removing the padding which appears -left and -right of this `img` element. I do not want to remove the root `container-fluid` element's padding as this ruins things for the preceding content; I only want to disable it on this one image.

The HTML which references the Bootstrap reads thus:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="images/section-image-02.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I've uploaded a visual to illustrate the effect below.

The padding i am trying to remove appears in blue alongside the image itself.

[image: Padding issue]

Comment: since you prefer not to ruin the fluid class padding.why not add an id to that element so that other elements with the same class would not be affected? just a thought here

Comment: Apologies for my late reply! I had thrown a `#` in there to see if it would target that element, but nothing's happening. I think this might be a case of specificity that I'm just not getting, or perhaps i need to use a series of containers in order to achieve the layout that I want. I'm going to rebuid this page at least partially to see if there's something I've missed.